EFBundle - detect that no migrations were applied
In the event that my generated EFBundle.exe does not find any migrations to be necessary for the database instance, the only indication seems to be this line in the output
No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date.

The return code is 0, same as if it applied a hundred necessary migrations.
Do I really have to just scan the output for that string?
